# Spotfire curve fitting

Tags: spotfire

I have an scatter plot, and want to see the line only fitting for marked points. Is there any way to do that in Spotfire? I know how to make a line fitting for all points but I don’t know how to fit the line base on the markings. Thanks in advance for your help.

MS

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a setting to have a best fit line only on the marked data.  However, you could create a details visualization based on the marked data and then perform your best fit on that.